# React: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource from MovieDB API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, themoviedb-api

I am needing to fetch data from the MovieDB API and I have my code setup to where I just want to return some data after I hit the search button, but when I hit the search button I get back:

> NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

My code so far consists of this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
  const API_KEY = '664e565dee7eaa6ef924c41133a22b63';

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getMovies(){
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data.results)
      setMovies(data.results)
    }
    if(query !== "") getMovies();

  }, [query])


  return (
   <div>
     <form>
    
       <button onClick={() => setQuery("Avengers")}type="submit">Search</button>
       <p>{JSON.stringify(movies)}</p>
     </form>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If use (and query ='Avengers'):

```
${query}`
```

in API URL, you get this (Every record is corelated with Avengers movie)

[image]

---

Try this - It's not include more advanced functions, which you need.
But it's good fundamental for bulding next features:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


    const App2 = () => {
        const API_KEY = '664e565dee7eaa6ef924c41133a22b63';

        const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
        const [query, setQuery] = useState('Avengers');

        useEffect(() => {
            async function getMovies(query) {
                await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=$query`)
                    .then(data => data.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data.results)
                        const result = data.results.map(obj => ({ popularity: obj.popularity, id: obj.id }));
                        console.log(result)
                        setMovies(result)
                        console.log(movies)
                    })
            }
            getMovies()
        }, [query])

        return (
            <div>
                {movies.map((movie, key) => (
                    <div key={key}>
                        <h1> {movie.popularity}</h1>
                        <h1>{movie.id}</h1>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default App2;
```

---

Here is your **schema from API** (only 1 object in array) (I used only **id** & **popularity**) - it's possible to use what you wish:

[image]